# How to convert depth16 image into 3D models in Android Studio

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera2, point-clouds, depth

Most of my work now is based on this project: https://github.com/plluke/tof

I can already get depth image on my Android phone (see below) but my ultimate goal is to **generate a 3D model.**

Is there any way to implement this transformation in Android Studio？As far as I know, here is a format called `DEPTH_POINT_CLOUD` in `ImageFormat`, so I thought there might be some way to create a point cloud from the depth image data in Android studio?

[image: depth image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Asking for libraries or tutorials is considered off-topic, see: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What you are trying to do is called [photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry) which is a non-trivial topic of image processing. See https://github.com/awesome-photogrammetry/awesome-photogrammetry for resources.

Comment: before you can make a 3D model, you need a 3D **point cloud**. if you have the depth image, you just need to turn each pixel into a 3D point, which involves a "camera matrix" (focal length [pixels] calculated from focal length [mm] / pixel pitch [µm]) -- I would strongly recommend that you remove that photo you took of your computer screen and replace it with a proper screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.